# FFMpeg and Sequence Video

Tags: ffmpeg

I understand that you can use ffmpeg to serve a sequence of images as video, while the images are being generated. Is this correct?

Is there exists a way, where the ffserver can be used to serve a rtsp stream, using a list of mp4 files, which are getting generated sequentially (one at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out one can write a simple MJPEG Streamer, which can stream a set of images continuously, (sending the same frame while the new one is still getting generated).  You can feed this to a FFMPEG Server to get a RTSP Stream out of it

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that you can use ffmpeg to serve a sequence of images as video, while the images are being generated. Is this correct?

You mean the images getting saved, and converted by FFMPEG, and streamed as video in real time? That sounds very unlikely. All approaches I know need the images to be present before you do the ffmpeg call.

See e.g. [this extensive tutorial](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)